# Compile Programs Depend on <windows.h> Without Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Is it possible to compile a c++ program that depends on `windows.h` without having to install the full visual c++ package?

I've just written some small program that calls some functions defined in `windows.h` (such as `ShellExecute`).

I don't want to install the entire visual studio package just to compile something this small. So I'm wondering if it's possible just to install the minimum package (just the compiler and the libraries).

Thanks,

Comment: Without Visual Studio or the Visual C++ package??

Comment: @Cicada I've never really used the visual studio ide. I don't want the ide in general. (I don't mind the compiler and libraries)

Comment: Your two choices are mingw or the windows sdk (which comes with an older C++ compiler IIRC). However, no reason to not install the visual c++ ide.

Comment: @JesseGood I almost never touch the windows dependent stuff... This is just something really small... I have mingw installed, so I guess that's enough?

Comment: I use the Windows API with MinGW a lot. It's very possible. I haven't seen support for the Vista+ APIs, though. I have to use VS for those.

Comment: Generally yes, but as chris just mentioned, depending on your mingw version, etc. it might not support it (also mingw doesn't support everything in the winapi).

Comment: MinGW - if you want to use cross-platform GCC compiler (tool-chain). And Windows SDK for VC++ compiler-linker. Plus you should install the libraries from Redistributable package (as far as i remember). I really think in case of VC++ you should install complete IDE (you can use it or not afterwards but everything needed will be in place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, however you need to obtain all the libraries and headers.
Perhaps you should install the express version, and choose a minimal install.
Igonre the IDE itself.

Comment: Windows SDK is probably easier than VC++ Express--won't even install the IDE period

Comment: @StephenLin: It's easier but the compiler it comes with is very old I think.

Comment: Hmm, apparently the latest Windows SDK drops the build environment entirely [(link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx)